# what is the ratio-consistent estimator?

Tags: terminology, high-dimensional

In high dimensional statistical inference I saw a term `Ratio-consistent estimator` which I am not familiar with it. anyone know the meaning of it?

As an example you can see [this article page 31.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279070596_A_note_on_high-dimensional_two-sample_test)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find exact definition of it! but As I saw in Chen an Qin's article (2010) to showing a estimator is consistent we should show: 
$$ E[\hat{\theta}] = \theta\Big(1+o(1)\Big)\quad \text{and}\quad \mathrm{var}\Big(\hat{(\theta)}\Big)= o(\theta^2).$$

Comment: Any estimator that has these two properties is ratio-consistent.  There is no "the" ratio-consistent estimator, any more than there is a "the" consistent estimator or "the" unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Theorem 2 for Chen and Qin (2010) is helpful. They have the following ratio consistent estimator $\widehat{\text{tr}(\Sigma_i^2)}$, which satisfies

$$\frac{\widehat{\text{tr}(\Sigma_i^2)}}{\text{tr}(\Sigma_i^2)}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}1 \;\;\; \text{as} \;\;\; n,p\rightarrow \infty.$$

From my understanding why ratio consistent estimator are helpful, over and above a consistent estimator, is because it ensures the estimator is well behaved in the limit of both $n,p\rightarrow \infty$ (a scenario common in high dimensional statistics) instead of just $n\rightarrow \infty$ (how a consistent estimator is defined).